# Does $\sqrt{(x)} = (b)$ implies $(b)^m = (x)$ for some positive integer $m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an integral domain, assume the principle ideals satisfies the relation that $\sqrt{(x)} = (b)$ does this implies exist some integer $m$ such that $(b^m) = (x)$.

---

My attempt: since $b \in \sqrt{(x)}$ this implies $b^m \in (x)$ for some $m$ and therefore $(b^m )\subset (x)$ conversely is obvious that $(x) \subset (b)$. Is it possible to show that $(b^m) = (x)$?

Comment: $\sqrt{12\Bbb Z}=6\Bbb Z$

Comment: nice example thank you .